# RewriteCond/Rewrite Rule - Apache 2

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

at the moment I use these rewrite rules/conditions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/forum/.* https://mineyourmind.net/forum/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/contao/.* https://mineyourmind.net/contao/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/contao
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mineyourmind\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://mineyourmind.net/de%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

They work perfect and every rewrite should stay the same instead of one.

If you visit mineyourmind.de (the main/home site) I don´t wont it to redirect to mineyourmind.net/de. It should redirected to mineyourmind.net that the rewrite of the .net site can decide the language.

I couldn´t get this working, how would you manage this ?

---

**Edit:**

There is **no** problem with these rewrite rules and I use them in the apache site config. I just want that every which goes to mineyourmind.de (root url) is directed to mineyourmind.net and **not** to mineyourmind.net/de. All the other redirection should stay the same.

**Edit2:**

- mineyourmind.de/ -> mineyourmind.net
- mineyourmind.de/forum -> mineyourmind.net/forum/
- mineyourmind.de/contao -> mineyourmind.net/contao
- mineyourmind.de/* -> mineyourmind.net/de/*

'*' = all other sites (not root, not forum/*, not contao/*)

Comment: You are using permanent redirects, which means the browser caches the redirect. It might be using the old redirects. Change `[R=301]` into `[R]` (temporary redirect). Then clear the cache of your browser and add the rule that should redirect the root of your website to the prefered url.

Comment: nah, I never use chrome for redirect tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?((?:forum|contao).*)$ https://mineyourmind.net/$1 [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mineyourmind\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://mineyourmind.net/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(contao|forum) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mineyourmind\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://mineyourmind.net/de%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This will skip `mineyourmind.de (the main/home site)` to be redirected to `mineyourmind.net` because of use `^/?.+$` regex that makes sure that it is not home/root page.

Comment: mineyourmind.de still redirects to mineyourmind.net/de and not to mineyourmind.net.

Comment: So you're sending request as: `http://mineyourmind.de/` it gets redirected to: `http://mineyourmind.net/` ?

Comment: When the user trys to access mineyourmind.de/ he should be redirected to mineyourmind.net/ and not to mineyourmind.net/de/ as it works atm

Comment: just edited the top post again, to make it more clear, I´m gonna try it again, ty.

Comment: Yes I understood your requirement from your comment and my lasted answer should satisfy all of your requirements.

Comment: still doesn´t work. mhh. I tested it with opera and firefox. I also tried to change the url to https://mineyourmind.net/test, but it still redirects to .net/de

Comment: Yes you need to start Apache

Comment: mhh, than it doesn´t work. I just deleted all redirects and reloaded apache and I couldn´t reach the site, as soon as they are back in, it redirects me to mineyourmind.net/de/

Comment: Most likely it is because of browser caching. Try this request in a new browser OR clear your browser cache.

Comment: Do you want `http://mineyourmind.net/` OR `https://mineyourmind.net/` for `http://mineyourmind.de/`

Comment: Ok, used a redirect check now and it seems to be working thank you. But still one more question, why is this "https://mineyourmind.de/forum/categories/deutsch.55/" redirecting to "https://mineyourmind.net/forum/" and not to "https://mineyourmind.net/forum/categories/deutsch.55/"

Comment: Alright for `/forum/` I copied your rule and that needs a correction too, let me edit it.

Comment: these dump browsers, speed is the only thing that matters for them. Is there anyway to set them in devmode, that they dont cache so much ?

Comment: Every modern browser like FF, Chrome, Safari etc have a private browsing option.